# What are the (dis)advantages of putting a child in a nursery or pre-school even when one parent is at home?

Tags: pre-schooler, working-parents

It is something I have always thought about, but never asked.  We have put our kids into kindergarten/nursery even though my wife doesn't work.  We decided that the benefits for our children outweighed the negatives.  I believe that it makes the kids more sociable, teaches them to share, and to operate responsibly socially.

The negatives are there, of course; I love the fact my kids benefitted from having mum at home all the time (nursery was always part time), but they always seemed ill for 6 months, which meant I had to suffer more and more ridiculous illnesses, costs are obviously high now (up to £1200 pounds per month) and there's a lot of anxiety to start with on both sides.

We are literally dropping our thirsd child any day now, and I want to ask myself it is really is the right thing to do.  It feels quite mean to do it, with mum home all the time, but I am sure there are great benefits.

Whats your take on it?

Comment: *Literally* dropping a child? No, that's not the right thing to do ;-) Children are fragile with many small bits. They can be difficult to glue together again if they break. (Sorry for this joke, but I felt I *had* to comment on the *literal*. Just for fun!)

Comment: We're in a pool, so it will drop straight into water, so it is literal Torben ;)

Comment: Wow, I've hear good things about that method! Wish you all the best!

Comment: This is so dependent on the country. In Poland toddler day care costs 800 PLN per month, and a Nanny costs 1000 PLN. In other countries a Nanny would cost several times as much as day-care.

Comment: @Lennart - A friend employs foreign nannies here as they work out to be about the same price, for the wages.  Obviously, they have to house them and feed them too, but the rate is around £600 a month for a live in nanny.

Comment: At the risk of having my answer there downvoted, I think this question is related, and might have useful information for you: http://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/1191/what-is-the-impact-on-kids-of-having-two-working-parents

Comment: How old are the kids?

Answer (score 3):

***Edit: This answer was written before I realized that the OP is in the UK. It is very US-centric, citing problems (such as poor nutrition) caused by the way the US regulates and funds day-care facilities.***

### Pros:

- Day care frees up time that a parent who would normally be charged with child care can use to work or tend to other responsibilities.
- Day care can give a child who is not used to being around other children the chance to learn to make friends before they go to school for the first time.

### Cons:

- It is *extremely* rare for a day care to do more than "kid warehousing", so unless you've found an exceptional one, your children may be missing out on the chance to learn pre-school skills that they need.
- The idea of children socializing (i.e. teaching correct social behavior to) other children is *absurd*.  Adults (such as parents) should be teaching children correct behavior.  Otherwise, they won't learn what you want them to, they'll learn only what makes sense to a toddler as clueless as they are.
- Day care is expensive.
- Day care typically exposes your children to a bunch of kids from families that don't share your social values, at an age where your children are too young to understand the difference, or to communicate to caregivers that they are being hurt or bullied.
- Day care nutrition is usually very poor.

### Other:

- Every day care is different.  In an exceptionally good day care, some or all of the cons above may not apply.
- Kids not in day care can just as easily learn to make friends by playing with other kids at a playground, going to a playgroup, or getting along with cousins at family events.

### Conclusion:

A really good day care can be a workable solution for kids whose parents need to work, kids who are very timid and have trouble making friends, etc.  However, the popular idea that somehow day care workers are magically better at instilling good manners (or worse -- that children should socialize one another) than good parents is simply false.  Kids at home with an attentive parent get much more attention, more opportunities to learn, and more individualized treatment than children in day care generally do.

Comment: I would add this is the UK we're talking about.  If the child is under 4, they have to have a maximum of 4 kids to their charge.  I also admit, we vetted our Nursery to ensure they did structured learning.  As for the the other cons, I'd have to down mark that, as it's not fact that nutrition is poor, just a subjective opinion.  Behavour wise, I wasn't intimating the children teach each other how to socialise, mroe that they are forced to oeprate within guidelines set by the nursery which teaches them a social code.

Comment: and Nursery kids don't get bullied if the staff are on the boil.  we have an educational body in the UK called Ofsted who make reports on these institutions, and the local councils also monitor them.  I should have said this was eaimed at the UK, not the US

Comment: Can you provide proof Hedgemadge, not opinion?

Comment: @Hairy Proof of what?  I think that each point should be self-evident (with the exception of the bit about nutrition, which I wrote not having noticed you are not in the US -- the US government dictates what foods may be served in licensed day cares here, and the standards are a disaster).

Comment: I have seen Madge.  However, the rest isn't substantiated by fact.  Day care, for me, is pretty much only afforded by middle class, middle income, and above, parents, as it is so ferociously expensive.  You have added opinions as almost fact, and I have responded accordingly.  I think kid warehousing is not prevalent, I think the kids DO learn social values (sharing, playing, learning).  In short, I thought your reply poorly thought hout, hence the down vote.

Comment: @Hairy Interesting... I'll edit to indicate that my answer is US-centric.  I did not realize things were so different in the UK.  On this side of the pond, day care is heavily regulated to very low standards, and the vast majority of children in day care come from families that got them there on government assistance.

Comment: nps Hedgemage.  In the UK, it's almost entirely privately run and regulated by the local councils and central government.  There are bad ones, but these tend to get closed quite quickly.  One near by was closed after failing a cleanliness standard recently.  I've bene there and thought it ok.  we have a fairly good standard of care, that I have seen, in UK nurserys.

Comment: @Hairy I imagine the difference lies largely in the fact that US day cares are funded primarily through welfare programs -- this both limits the money they have to work with and motivates the government to over-regulate.

Comment: I'd say so Mage!

Comment: Madge usually I respect your opinions, but this one seems to be more from a bad experience you had, its one answer of yours I disagree with.  Few of your points I find self-evident but then everyone has bad experiences.  I have never seen ay cares funded only from welfare programs, although I don't run in those circles I don't think they are representative.

Comment: @MichaelF I'll have to look up the stat again when I'm not at work, but was something like 68% of day care attendence nationwide is paid for with government vouchers or through tax rebates.  Since it is against the law for day cares to reveal which children are paid for with vouchers, and they have no way of knowing which parents receive tax rebates for their care, what makes you think you would "see" day cares being funded mostly (I never said only) through welfare programs.

Comment: It's one point madge and off the topic of the question, I just found it less than helpful for the answer or a comment as to how a vast majority of children are there.  Same as the kid warehousing, I'm sure they exist but I saw many day cares that were not like that.  I think you are mostly overgeneralizing.

Comment: Socializing is not about teaching correct behavior, but about learning to play the social games.

Comment: @Lennart - I think this was my original point; learning how to interact with each other, in a socially acceptable way i.e. no tbeating the other kid over the head with a hammer because he wants to use it.  We found biting was the most dangerous  activity metted out to the kids.

Comment: While I agree that this answer is overgeneralized, at least there was acknowledgement that some day care programs are better than others, and not all the cons may apply to all the cases.  I think it is a valid point about socialization, as well, however it is a narrow interpretation.  Not all socialization is mimicking how other children behave.  Some of it involves dealing with negative situations, and can be just as important, as Hairy and Lennart pointed out.

Comment: The vast majority of daycare standards in the US are made at the city, county, and state level.  National standards are minimal because it's not the federal government's job.

Answer (score 3):

We put our son in day care for one year, basically the one before Kindergarten, more for him to socialize with some other kids - get more structured play time and make some friends so when he started kindergarten it was an easier transition.  So we looked for a pre-school that had kids going to the same school as my son, and found one that was pretty good.  They did in class learning, play time, snack time (though its more what we sent not from the school) and they did the ABC's and early numbers - basically skills they knew our kindergarten would expect.

Not sure about Mage's experience but sure in some areas of the US there are guidelines that are lacking, like many US regulations that go for a common denominator but you can find exceptional pre-schools if you look.  Find ones where the parents are involved, in my town education brings out the parents who are very involved in PTO and class communities.  From pre-school we got more of an introduction to the town, we were new, as well as got play dates and learned about the teachers in the school.

In talking with other parents I knew most pre-schools required specific snacks for the day, or lunches if it was full day, but had limits on what to bring due to food allergies.

My wife got more time to herself, to do things around the house, or met other parents so it was a positive.

In the US day care is not cheap, though you can find affordable options, but you get what you pay for.

You will get illnesses, kids first exposures seem to be in schools and pre-schools, expect that more as the kids get older.

I'd say if you can afford it, and your wife needs more time to focus on younger kids, it might be worthwhile, its also a good way to get your children more used to groups, group play and learning how to interact.